# PHP- conflito de código - página em branco

Tags: php, sql

O seguinte código permite o usuario fazer log in e direcionar para uma determinada pagina, ou fazer login como administrador e direcionar para outra pagina.
O login do usuario esta funcionando, no entando ao fazer log out aparece undefinied variable na linha 28 e 29. E se tento fazer login como administrador para alem de nao redirecionar a pagina fica em branco.

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM registo WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($pass);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        if(password_verify($password,$pass)) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['user'] = true;
            header("Location: home.php");
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Email/password is incorrect.</h3> <br>
                    Click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>
                  </div>";
        }
    }
    } else {
        $ustmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM Admin WHERE email=?");
        $ustmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $email = $_POST['email'];//linha 28
        $password = $_POST['password']; //linha 29
        $ustmt->execute();
        $ustmt->store_result();
        $ustmt->bind_result($pass);
        $ustmt->fetch();
        if($ustmt->num_rows > 0) echo "hello"; //linha 36 {
        if(password_verify($password,$pass)) {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['Admin'] = true;
                header("Location: adminarea.html");
            } else { //linha 47
                echo "<div class='form'>
                        <h3>Email/password is incorrect.</h3> <br>
                        Click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>
                      </div>";
            }

} else {
    echo "<div class='form'>
                        <h3>You are now logged out!.</h3> <br>
                        Click here to <a href='home.php'>Home</a>
                      </div>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: você precisa adicionar o código do formulário também.

Comment: Esse código tá muito estranho. Você verifica se a variável `email` existe e executa um código, se não executa outro, porém os dois blocos precisam do e-mail.

Comment: Tem erro grave de lógica isso ai. Como você quer usar `$_POST['email']` se você já está dizendo que ela não existe ao cair no `ELSE` da condição `if (isset($_POST['email']))`.

Comment: aquilo que eu pretendo é se for inserido um email de usuario redicionar para determinada pagina, se for email de administrador redicionar para uma pagina diferente. alguma sugestão de resolução?

Comment: Tenho estado a a fazer echo em cada linha. e na linha 36 coloquei e reclamou do else na linha 47. pf editei o codigo! mas no entanto nao estou a conseguir resolver.

Comment: Sim, porque não faz o mínimo de sentido fazer o que você fez. O `else` não pode existir sem o `if`.

Comment: (1) O e-mail e senha dos usuários e administradores são informados no mesmo formulário? (2) Como você fará para diferenciar se é uma tentativa de login de usuário ou de admin? Será tentado primeiro logar como usuário e se não conseguir, tentar como admin? (3) Considerando duas tabelas distintas, é possível que exista dois cadastros iguais de usuário e admin? (4) Se sim, a conta deve ser considerada usuário ou admin?

Comment: o formulario é o mesmo,como eu ja disse antes, antes de atribuir bind parameter estava a funcionar na perfeiçao. ao fazer log in quando clico submeter deteta se é email de usuario ou email de admin, ou seja o codigo tenta ver se é email de usuario se sim tudo bem vai para x pagina. se deteta q é email de Admin vai para outra pagina!havendo duas tabelas distintas nao ha hipotese que de haver dois cadastros iguais.

Comment: Você está fazendo essa garantia que não haverá registros iguais em código? Aliás, primeiro tente implementar a solução do Wendel. Ela faz um pouco mais de sentido, por unir as duas tabelas em uma. Simplifica muito o código.

Answer (score 0):

O erro de `undefined variable` ocorre no item 18. O código está comentado e é auto-explicativo.

```
<?php

// (0) Não falta um session_start() aqui?

require('config.php');

// (1) Verifica-se se existe um e-mail na requisição:
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // (2) Monta uma consulta à tabela registo (seria registro)?
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM registo WHERE email=?");

    // (3) Associa a variável $email à consulta:
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    // (4) Recupera os valores de $email e $password:
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // (5) Executa a consulta:
    $stmt->execute();

    // (6) Armazena os resultados
    $stmt->store_result();

    // (7) Associa a variável $pass ao resultado da consulta:
    $stmt->bind_result($pass);

    // (8) Obtém o resultado da consulta:
    $stmt->fetch();

    // (9) Verifica se há resultados:
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

        // (10) Valida a senha informada comparando com a do banco de dados:
        if(password_verify($password,$pass)) {

            // (11) Armazena as sessões:
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['user'] = true;

            // (12) Redireciona o usuário:
            header("Location: home.php");

        // (13) A senha informada é inválida:
        } else {

            // (14) Exibe uma mensagem de erro:
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Email/password is incorrect.</h3> <br>
                    Click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>
                  </div>";
        }

    }

// (15) A variável $_POST["email"] não existe:
} else {

    // (16) Monta uma consulta à tabela Admin:
    $ustmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM Admin WHERE email=?");

    // (17) Associa a variável $email à consulta:
    $ustmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    // (18) Recupera os valores de $email, que não existe (vide 15), e $password:
    $email = $_POST['email']; //linha 28
    $password = $_POST['password']; //linha 29

    // (19) Executa a consulta:
    $ustmt->execute();

    // (20) Armazena os resultados da consulta:
    $ustmt->store_result();

    // (21) Associa a variável $pass ao resultado da consulta:
    $ustmt->bind_result($pass);

    // (22) Obtém o primeiro resultado:
    $ustmt->fetch();

    // (23) Veririca se há resultados:
    if($ustmt->num_rows > 0) {

        // (24) Verifica se a senha informada é válida:
        if(password_verify($password,$pass)) {

            // (25) Sim, armazena os valores em sessão:
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['Admin'] = true;

            // (26) Redireciona o usuário:
            header("Location: adminarea.html");

        // (27) A senha não é válida:
        } else {

            // (28) Exibe uma mensagem de erro:
            echo "<div class='form'>
                    <h3>Email/password is incorrect.</h3> <br>
                    Click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>
                  </div>";
        }

    // (29) Não há registros:
    } else {

        // (30) Exibe uma mensagem de erro (logout? deveria ser dados incorretos):
        echo "<div class='form'>
                <h3>You are now logged out!.</h3> <br>
                Click here to <a href='home.php'>Home</a>
              </div>";
    }
}

?>
```

Solução será dada assim que você definir uma lógica plausível para o problema.

Comment: este codigo ja deu na perfeiçao ai eu fui adicionar o bind parameter e deixou de funcionar!

Comment: Mas é exatamente o seu código, só que comentado. Ele não vai funcionar.

Comment: o que es estou tentando dizer é que o codigo que coloquei na pergunta antes estava funcionando na perfeição mas ai fui colocar o bind parameter e deixou de funcionar!

Comment: Se estava funcionando, era por sorte. Não deveria. Leia esse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207422/php-conflito-de-c%c3%b3digo-p%c3%a1gina-em-branco/207453?noredirect=1#comment424291_207422), responda-o e poderemos ver qual é a melhor solução.

Comment: respondendo a sua pergunta, a SESSION_START esta dentro de config.php. if isset inclui o if do usuario e do admin. este codigo reconhece se o email pertence a um usuario ou a um admin e consoante o email introduzido faz açoes diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Pra conseguir fazer o que você precisa teria que criar somente uma tabela pra armazenar todos os usuário. Você possui duas `registo` e `Admin`. Nessa tabela você teria, por exemplo:

```
user, email, password, type (Usuário e Administrador)
```

Assumindo que sua tabela ficasse com o nome de `usuarios`, o código ficaria assim:

```
<?php
require('config.php');

// Verifica se está passando o e-mail e senha
if (isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Seleciona o tipo pelo email e senha
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT type FROM usuarios WHERE email=? and password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($type);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['type']  = $type; // crio uma sessão com o tipo para facilitar a identificação ao invéz de ter duas sessões (user e admin)

        if $type = 'usuario' { // Se for usuário
            header("Location: home.php");
        } else { // Senão é admin
            header("Location: adminarea.html");
        }
    } else { // Caso não tenha encontrado pelo e-mail e senha informado
        echo "<div class='form'>
            <h3>Email/password is incorrect.</h3> <br>
            Click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>
            </div>";
    }
}
?>
```